# Singular Value Decomposition Problem. How could I prove this better?

Tags: linear-algebra

- Statement: If $A$ is a $4$x$3$ matrix, then the matrix $\Sigma $ in any singular value decomposition of A is $4$ X $r$, where $r$ is the number of positive singular values of $A$.

Q: Is this always, sometimes, or never true?

Work: First, I tried this statement with a case like $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
 0& 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$. I ended with singular values of $0,1$ and $\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0& 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $. Here, we only had 2 positive singular values, yet $r=3$. Using another example of $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
1& 0 & 1\\ 
1 & 0 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$. For singular values, I got $3.020, 0.936, 0$. and $r=3$. So that makes me come to believe that this is sometimes true. I was curious on how to prove this better.

Answer (score 2):

The full SVD will often have $\Sigma$ having the same dimensionality as the original matrix. However, when there are singular values equal to 0, we can remove rows and columns of $\Sigma$ (and $U$ and $V$) such that $\Sigma$ is a $d \times d$ matrix, where $d$ is the number of non-zero singular values.

We can then write $A$ as the product of a $(4 \times d)$ matrix, a $(d \times d)$ matrix and a $(d \times 3)$ matrix.

This is also the approach used to reduce the dimensionality of a matrix: only keep the largest singular values, and drop the others.

Comment: So technically, would this statement still be sometimes true because this would only hold true if it wasn't solely positive singular values. (if there was a negative singular value it wouldn't hold true).

Comment: Right. In that case we would keep those that have the largest *absolute* value. Sorry, I'm too used to only working with positive semidefinite matrices and forgot to take that case into account.